# Sometimes "hear" means "listen to". Is it correct to say "I heard his lecture carefully"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

According Oxford dictionary,

> [hear](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hear?q=hear): [transitive] (not used in the progressive tenses): to listen or
> pay attention to somebody/something
>
> He knows that the crowd wants to hear those songs.
>
> Have you ever heard him lecture?

My question is that:

When can we use "**hear**" to mean "**listen to**"?

For example, can we say "**I heard his lecture carefully**" instead of "**I listened to his lecture carefully**"?

Answer (score 2):

"Heard" is used more generally, i.e., as in the perception of any sound, but if you're being specifically attentive, *listened carefully* would be the better way to state it.

- He *barely* heard the insect scuttling.
- He *clearly* heard the thunder.
- He *listened carefully* to the weak signal.

So *heard* is the perception, *listened* includes the thought processes.